# How to find the whether a service has Automatic (Delayed Start) startup type in registry for Windows apart from Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10

Tags: windows, service, registry

In my application, I need to fetch the details of services using the wmi32 service class. In this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service), it is mentioned that the property `DelayedAutoStart` is only supported for Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10. I need to fetch the same for other OS too. Is there any way to find the
Automatic (Delayed Start) in the registry for lower Windows version?

Comment: Windows7/8 have same registry keys for delayed service start

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you mean this key -> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<ServiceName>` -> Value name: `DelayedAutostart`

Comment: Yes. `This property is not supported before Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10` - Probably `Win32_Service class` didn't support this property, but Win8/7 services could have this value.